# Couldn't find any reference for tsc -p command

Tags: typescript, electron, typescript-typings, electron-builder, react-typescript

I am building an electron + typescript + react app.
At one of the blogs I see they have used `tsc -p electron`
I am totally confused what -p is used for! is it something related to plugins?

```
"electron:dev": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"wait-on http://127.0.0.1:3000 && tsc -p electron && electron .\" ",
```

I tried searching for the possible explanation in [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) but couldn't find any reference for `tsc -p`.

Comment: `-p` is the shortcut for `--project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Tobias S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8613630/tobias-s) for answering.

```
-p is the shortcut for --project
```